# if statement in c not output correctly

Tags: c, if-statement

```c
    printf("Golongan Rumah Tangga A1\n");
    printf("Masukan pemakaian \n");
    scanf("%f", &pemakaian);

    if ( pemakaian <= 10 ) {
        tarif = 1.780;
        printf("Tarif : %.3f\n", tarif);
    }
    else if ( pemakaian > 11 || pemakaian <= 20 ) {
        tarif = 2.060;
        printf("Tarif : %.3f\n", tarif);
    }
```

when I input 2 the result is still 2,060

which should be 1,780

this is my full code

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {

int klaster, golongan, listrik, pemakaian;
double berm, tarif;

    printf("Program air\n");

    printf("Pilih klaster\n ");
    printf("1. Rumah Tangga\n");
    printf("2. Usaha\n");

    scanf("%d", &klaster);
    if (klaster == 1) {
        printf("pilih golongan\n");
        printf("1. Subsidi\n");
        printf("2. tanpa subsidi\n");
        scanf("%d", &golongan);
        if( golongan == 1) {
            printf("Masukan daya listik\n");
            scanf("%d", &listrik);

            printf("Masukan lebar berm\n");
            scanf("%f", &berm);

            if (listrik == 450 && berm <=3.99 ) {
                printf("Golongan Rumah Tangga A1\n");
                printf("Masukan pemakaian \n");
                scanf("%f", &pemakaian);

                if ( pemakaian <=10 && pemakaian > 0 ) {
                    tarif = 1.780;
                    printf("Tarif : %.3f\n", tarif);
                }
                else if ( pemakaian > 11 ) {
                        tarif = 2.060;
                        printf("Tarif : %.3f\n", tarif);
                }
            } 
            else if (listrik == 900 && berm <=3.99 ) {
                printf("Golongan Rumah Tangga A1\n");
                printf("Masukan pemakaian \n");
                scanf("%f", &pemakaian);

                if ( pemakaian <= 10 ) {
                    tarif = 1.780;
                    printf("Tarif : %.3f\n", tarif);
                }
                else if ( pemakaian > 11 || pemakaian <= 20 ) {
                    tarif = 2.060;
                    printf("Tarif : %.3f\n", tarif);
                }
                else if ( pemakaian > 20 ) {
                    tarif = 5.880;
                    printf("Tarif : %.3f\n", tarif);
                }
            }


        }else {
            printf("Input yang benar woiii");
        }

    }else{
        printf("Input yang benar woiii");
        
    }
}
```

Comment: What's the type of `pemakaian`?

Comment: Show your complete code.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show us a [mre]. Also please show us the full input and output when running the program (preferably copy-pasted as plain text).

Comment: You might need to change the || into && as well

Comment: Your compiler should raise a warning for parameter type mismatch. If not, increase warning level.

Comment: Earlier in the code you have `if ( pemakaian <=10 && pemakaian > 0 )`, which is the correct way to check a range. But then later you have `if ( pemakaian > 11 || pemakaian <= 20 )` which is wrong. What happened? Is it just a typo? A slip of the mind?

Comment: what happens when you enter 11?

Answer (score 1):

When reading a float with `scanf("%f", &pemakaian)` (notice the `%f` flag), a binary value of 0b01000000000000000000000000000000 is read for a decimal input 2, which later is stored in an int variable pemakaian as a 4194304 decimal.

You can find out more about the binary format of the float numbers in C [here](https://www.cs.yale.edu/homes/aspnes/pinewiki/C(2f)FloatingPoint.html#:%7E:text=Any%20number%20that%20has%20a,for%20the%20exponent%3A%206.022e23.).

The easiest solution for this is to either read an integer with `scanf("%d", &pemakaian)` (notice the `%d` flag), or initialize pemakaian as a float.

Comment: pemakaian type is int

Comment: @Esa it needs to be a `float`, or scanf needs to be updated to `scanf("%d", &pemakaian)` to read an int

Comment: thank you very much, it turns out that I entered the wrong scanf in the scanf, even though I made an int variable